# Replace a number in a string by another character specified by a list of tuples

Tags: python, regex, pandas, tuples

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
    variable       value
0   Varx_(0,_0)     0.0
1   Varx_(0,_1)     0.0
2   Varx_(0,_10)    0.0
3   Varx_(0,_100)   0.0
4   Varx_(1,_0)     0.0
5   Varx_(1,_1)     0.0
6   Varx_(1,_10)    0.0
7   Varx_(1,_100)   0.0
...
```

For each row in the column variable, I would like to replace the first number inside the  parenthesis by a correspondent number specified by the following list of tuples:

`transform_o = [(0, '33'),(2, '601'),(1, '148'),(3, '646'),(4, '1192')...]`

For each row in the column variable, I would like to replace the second number inside the  parenthesis by a correspondent number specified by the following list of tuples:

`transform_d = [(0, '1.0'),(1, '3.0'),(100, '4.0'),(10, '5.0')]`

transform_d and transform_o have different sizes.

For example, at the end I need to obtain the following result

```
    variable          value
0   Varx_(33,_1.0)      0.0
1   Varx_(33,_3.0)      0.0
2   Varx_(33,_5.0)      0.0
3   Varx_(33,_4.0)      0.0
4   Varx_(148,_1.0)     0.0
5   Varx_(148,_3.0)     0.0
6   Varx_(148,_5.0)     0.0
7   Varx_(148,_4.0)     0.0
```

I think that  the solution will probably use regex, but since I am still learning how to use them, a little help would definitely save me

Thanks

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your `transform_o` and `transform_d` to dict. Then use `re.findall()` to find integer in `variable` column. At last replace value with `re.sub()`.

```py
import re

transform_o = [(0, '33'),(2, '601'),(1, '148'),(3, '646'),(4, '1192')]
transform_d = [(0, '1.0'),(1, '3.0'),(100, '4.0'),(10, '5.0')]

transform_o = dict(transform_o)
transform_d = dict(transform_d)

def replace(value):
    o, d = re.findall(r'\((\d+),_(\d+)\)', value)[0]
    o_ = transform_o[int(o)]
    d_ = transform_d[int(d)]
    result = re.sub(r"\((\d+),_(\d+)\)", f"({o_},_{d_})", value)
    return result

df['variable'] = df['variable'].apply(replace)
```

```
print(df)

          variable  value
0   Varx_(33,_1.0)    0.0
1   Varx_(33,_3.0)    0.0
2   Varx_(33,_5.0)    0.0
3   Varx_(33,_4.0)    0.0
4  Varx_(148,_1.0)    0.0
5  Varx_(148,_3.0)    0.0
6  Varx_(148,_5.0)    0.0
7  Varx_(148,_4.0)    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
o = dict(transform_o)
d = dict(transform_d)

df['variable'] = df['variable'].str.replace(r'(?P<o>\d+),_(?P<d>\d+)',
                   lambda r: '._'.join([o[int(r['o'])], d[int(r['d'])]]))
```

```
>>> df
          variable  value
0   Varx_(33._1.0)    0.0
1   Varx_(33._3.0)    0.0
2   Varx_(33._5.0)    0.0
3   Varx_(33._4.0)    0.0
4  Varx_(148._1.0)    0.0
5  Varx_(148._3.0)    0.0
6  Varx_(148._5.0)    0.0
7  Varx_(148._4.0)    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string methods to do this -

1st convert list of tuples to dict.

```
transform_o = [(0, '33'),(2, '601'),(1, '148'),(3, '646'),(4, '1192')]
transform_o_dict = {str(item[0]):str(item[1]) for item in transform_o}
# print(transform_o_dict)
```

Then use string methods to change the values -

```
numbers = df.variable.str.split('(').str[1].str.split(',').str[0].map(transform_o_dict)
df.variable = df.variable.str.split('(').str[0] + '(' + numbers + ',' + df.variable.str.split('(').str[1].str.split(',').str[1]
print(df)
```